# Android MediaRecorder Пишет видео в низком качестве

Tags: android, камера

Я реализовал видеозапись в своей программе. Также в данной активности выводятся показания акселерометра, но с этим все нормально.

```
package com.example.shelldrive;

import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.example.shelldrive.R;
import com.example.shelldrive.G_sensor.VideoRecorder;

public class VideoRecord extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        View.OnClickListener, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PreviewCallback,
        Camera.AutoFocusCallback, SensorEventListener
{

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView preview;
    private VideoRecorder recorder;

    private Button shotBtn;
    private Button recordBtn;
    private Boolean isRecording = false;

    private static final int IDM_PREF = 101;
    private static final int IDM_EXIT = 102;

    private int videoBitrate;
    private int videoFramerate;
    private int audioBitrate;
    private int audioSamplingrate;
    private int audioChannels;
    private int videoWidth;
    private int videoHeight;
    private int videoMaxDuration;
    private int videoMaxFileSize;

    private SensorManager mgr;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private TextView text;
    private float[] gravity = new float[3];
    private float[] motion = new float[3];
    private double ratio;
    private double mAngle;
    private int counter = 0;
    private float motion_test = 0;
    private float speed = 0;
    private float acseleration = 0;
    private float time_speed = 0;
    private boolean first_change = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // если хотим, чтобы приложение постоянно имело портретную ориентацию
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        // если хотим, чтобы приложение было полноэкранным
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // и без заголовка
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_reg);

        mgr = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        accelerometer = mgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // наше SurfaceView имеет имя SurfaceView01
        preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);

        surfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        // кнопка имеет имя Button01
        shotBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        shotBtn.setText("Shot");
        shotBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        recordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        recordBtn.setText("Start");
        recordBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        recorder = new VideoRecorder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        mgr.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        super.onResume();
        camera = Camera.open();
        recorder.open();

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        videoBitrate = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.video_br), "1500000"));
        videoFramerate = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.video_fr), "15"));
        audioBitrate = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.audio_br), "8000"));
        audioSamplingrate = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.audio_sr), "8000"));
        audioChannels = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.audio_ch), "1"));
        videoWidth = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.video_sz_w), "640"));
        videoHeight = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.video_sz_h), "480"));
        videoMaxDuration = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.max_duration), "0"));
        videoMaxFileSize = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.max_filesize), "0"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        mgr.unregisterListener(this, accelerometer);
        super.onPause();

        recorder.close();

        if (camera != null)
        {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // ignore
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Use a low-pass filter to get gravity. Motion is what's left over
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            gravity [i] = (float) (0.1 * event.values[i] + 0.9 * gravity[i]);
            motion[i] = event.values[i] - gravity[i];
        }

        // ratio is gravity on the Y axis compared to full gravity
        // should be no more than 1, no less than -1
        ratio = gravity[1]/SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        if(ratio > 1.0) ratio = 1.0;
        if(ratio < -1.0) ratio = -1.0;

        // convert ratio to radians to degrees, make negative if facing up
        mAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(ratio));
        if(gravity[2] < 0) {
            mAngle = -mAngle;
        }

        // Display every 10th value
        if(counter++ % 10 == 0) {
            time_speed = (float) 0.15;
            acseleration = (float) Math.sqrt(motion[0]*motion[0] + motion[1]*motion[1] + motion[2]*motion[2]);
            if (motion[2] < 0)
                speed = (float) (motion_test - acseleration*time_speed);
            else 
                speed = (float) (motion_test + acseleration*time_speed);
            if (first_change == false)
                speed = 0;
            motion_test = speed;
            String msg = String.format(
                "Raw values\nX: %8.4f\nY: %8.4f\nZ: %8.4f\n" +
                "Gravity\nX: %8.4f\nY: %8.4f\nZ: %8.4f\n" +
                "Motion\nX: %8.1f\nY: %8.1f\nZ: %8.1f\nAngle: %8.1f \nspeed: %8.0f",
                event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2],
                gravity[0], gravity[1], gravity[2],
                motion[0], motion[1], motion[2],
                mAngle, speed*3.6f);
            System.out.println("Y   " + speed);
            text.setText(msg);
            text.invalidate();
            counter=1;
            first_change = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_PREF, Menu.NONE, "Settings");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_EXIT, Menu.NONE, "Exit");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case IDM_PREF:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, SettingsScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case IDM_EXIT:
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;

        int previewSurfaceWidth = preview.getWidth();
        int previewSurfaceHeight = preview.getHeight();

        LayoutParams lp = preview.getLayoutParams();

        // здесь корректируем размер отображаемого preview, чтобы не было
        // искажений

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            // портретный вид
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            lp.height = previewSurfaceHeight;
            lp.width = (int) (previewSurfaceHeight / aspect);
        }
        else
        {
            // ландшафтный
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            lp.width = previewSurfaceWidth;
            lp.height = (int) (previewSurfaceWidth / aspect);
        }

        preview.setLayoutParams(lp);
        camera.startPreview();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == shotBtn)
        {
            // либо делаем снимок непосредственно здесь
            // либо включаем обработчик автофокуса

            // camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
            camera.autoFocus(this);
        }
        else if (v == recordBtn)
        {
            if (isRecording)
            {
                recorder.stop();

                try
                {
                    // запрещаем общий доступ к камере
                    camera.reconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // снова включаем preview камеры
                camera.startPreview();

                recordBtn.setText("Record");

                // включаем кнопку фотосъемки
                shotBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
                // выключаем кнопку фотосъемки
                shotBtn.setEnabled(false);

                // останавливаем preview камеры (иначе будет ошибка)
                camera.stopPreview();

                // разрешаем общий доступ к камере
                camera.unlock();

                // рекордер использует уже созданную камеру
                recorder.setCamera(camera);

                // задаем параметры, preview, имя файла и включаем запись
                try {
                    recorder.setRecorderParams(videoBitrate, audioBitrate, audioSamplingrate, audioChannels, videoFramerate, videoWidth, videoHeight, videoMaxDuration, videoMaxFileSize);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.setPreview(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
                recorder.start(String.format("/sdcard/CameraExample/%d.mp4", System.currentTimeMillis()));

                recordBtn.setText("Stop");
            }

            isRecording = !isRecording;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        // сохраняем полученные jpg в папке /sdcard/CameraExample/
        // имя файла - System.currentTimeMillis()

        try
        {
            File saveDir = new File("/sdcard/CameraExample/");

            if (!saveDir.exists())
            {
                saveDir.mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                    "/sdcard/CameraExample/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            os.write(paramArrayOfByte);
            os.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        // после того, как снимок сделан, показ превью отключается. необходимо
        // включить его
        paramCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean paramBoolean, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        if (paramBoolean)
        {
            // если удалось сфокусироваться, делаем снимок
            paramCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        // здесь можно обрабатывать изображение, показываемое в preview
    }
}
```

Здесь устанавливаю параметры и запускаю запись.

```
package com.example.shelldrive.G_sensor;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.view.Surface;

public class VideoRecorder 
{
    private MediaRecorder recorder;

    public VideoRecorder()
    {
    }

    public void open()
    {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    public void close()
    {
    if (recorder != null)
    {
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
    }

    public void start(String filename)
    {
    recorder.setOutputFile(filename);

    try
        {
        recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
    }

    public void setPreview(Surface surface)
    {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera)
    {
        recorder.setCamera(camera); 
    }

    public void setRecorderParams(int vbr, int abr, int asr, int ach, int vfr, int w, int h, int md, int mfs) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
    {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(vbr);
        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(abr);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(asr);
        recorder.setAudioChannels(ach);
        recorder.setVideoFrameRate(vfr);
        recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        recorder.setMaxDuration(md);
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(mfs);
        recorder.prepare();
    }

}
```

В параметрах выставлено разрешение 640 на 480. Когда воспроизвожу записанное видео, оно в очень низком качестве и сильно тормозит.
Чем выше разрешения, тем больше тормоза.
Воспроизводил в разных проигрывателях на телефоне. Везде одинаково плохо.
В чем проблема никак не могу понять. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что для перехвата битов с камеры вы используете `Camera.PreviewCallback` - ключевое слово здесь `Preview` - то есть предпросмотр. И естественно, он дает вам низкое разрешение.

Чтобы писать в нормальном качестве надо просто вызвать `Intent` записи на видео - например [как здесь](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html)

Comment: Но ведь Intent открывает стандартное приложение камеры. А мне нужно оставаться в моей активности. Или я чего-то не понял?
В классе VideoRecorder я вызываю методы для класса MediaRecorder prepare() и start(). Вроде как после этого биты должны быть записаны с параметрами, указанными в MediaRecorder.

Comment: Да, Intent открывает стандартное приложение камеры. Я думаю, что в рамках Java вам недостучаться напрямую до нормальных битов камеры - попробуйте NDK

Comment: Уже сделал. Действительно получал байты из Preview. Переделал по алгоритму из developer.google. Превью отдельно, отдельно запись видео с помощью MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

Лучшее качество из доступного.